# Display MongoId publicly or not?

Tags: mongodb

I'm bulding a small web application using mongodb and just thought if it's a good practice to show mongoIds publicly, in urls for example.

Now I'm using the following url structure for user profiles: http://example.com/user/MONGOID

Does this have any security flaws or is it discouraged in some other way?

Comment: It's not a security risk to show them. It's only an issue if you don't have security in front of display details for a given ID (as the IDs are very predictable and often could be guessed on a high traffic web site).

Comment: This question has been covered at least 2 times if you do a bit of a google search (I have answered this question twice), IDs are not super guessable since if you have a set then the user would have to guess the internal pid and machine id of each host (which is not visible outside) to make objectids that actually match data, from personal tests with PHP I found a spider would possibly have to iterate sets of calculations in excess of 10,000 times for a single _id in a large setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on many of things...

Using an ID in a URL is generally a bad idea. [According to OWASP, it ranks #4 in the top 10 web security vulnerabitiy list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References). But using it will not ruin your project.

To prevent the security vulnerability, you must either :

- Use it only on data that is public (like StackOverflow profiles)
- Have some code intercept the request and validate that the user has the rights to see the resource (a profile, a page, a document, etc.)

Using `_id` It also ties your public URL to the back-end. You will need some conversion if you change database technology. Or maybe you will need to run some changes that will result in the object being destroyed and created again, but with a different `_id`, like merging databases or something. You don't want your URL to change because of that.

Another thing is that `_id` does not have a good spatial distribution. It does not make a good sharding key. Being derived from a time stamp, all `_id` are close together, linear if you will. They will tend to go in the same shard (Mongo will spread them later, but [you want a key that has high cardinality](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/)).

So I prefer to pay now, and use a id field that is private to the application from the start. You can store it in the `_id` field if you want, but consider adding another key to your document, index it, and use that in your URLs.

Comment: The OWASP page talks about **unauthorized** direct object references. As long as you have proper domain object security implemented exposing ids is ok. And basically that's what most sites do.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not have security implications.

All the person would be able to do is to guess the Id of some user or to try to go through all Ids to get all users of the system.

Take stackoverflow as an example. They have the same pattern as you: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/352959` this is 352959 is you and there is nothing bad with it. The only thing that whenever you will enter this in your browser you will be redirected to  `http://stackoverflow.com/users/352959/king-julien`.

I can try to iterate through these numbers and the next guy is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/352960` but all I can found is that this is some john. And surely `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1` is the creator of the resource.